# Particle in a 3-D Box

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, physics, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Reading through my quantum mechanics book I've stumbled on a question any help would be great.

Suppose we had a 3-D square well i.e. $$V(x,y,z)=\begin{Bmatrix}
0 \ \text{if}\ 0\leq x \leq a \ , \ 0\leq y \leq b \ , \ 0\leq z \leq c \   \\ 
\infty \ \text{otherwise}
\end{Bmatrix}$$

For the first part of my question is *finding the eigenvalues of energy*. I firstly used the wave equation: $$\Psi (x,y,z)=A\sin\left(\frac{n_x \pi x}{a}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n_y \pi y}{b}\right)\sin\left(\frac{n_z \pi z}{c}\right)$$ and using $K_x=\frac{n_x \pi}{a}$ and by subbing this into the Schrodinger equation got my eigenvalues of energy to be: $$E=\frac{\pi^2 \hbar^2}{2m}\left ( \frac{n_x^2}{a^2} + \frac{n_y^2}{b^2} + \frac{n_z^2}{c^2} \right )$$

So my question leads to how would one compute the eigenstates of $\hat{H}$?

and also, say we had now our boundaries set to $a=b=c$, for a given value of energy $E$, is there only a single eigenstate?

I understand that at the 1st excited state there is degeneracy as there are 3 different wavefunctions with the same energy. And since there are many wavefunctions corresponding to different energies this would mean there are many eigenstates - so to that question the answer is no?

Comment: I think you missed one step in the understanding of the problem. You **already have** the eigenstates of $\hat H$ in form of the wavefunction $\Psi$. In fact you already imposed the conditions $\Psi(0,y,z)=\Psi(a,y,z)=0$ and similarly for the other dimensions, since you have the forms with the sine functions.

Comment: @Andrei aah right I see, so the result of the allowed energies being 'E' gives us the eigenstates of H in the form of the wavefunction defined above? - and is my answer to the last question where our new boundaries a=b=c correct?

Comment: In the case of $a=b=c$ how many linearly independent wave functions do you have for the ground state? From what I can see you only have the one.

Comment: @Spencer yes for the ground state there is only 1 wave function and 3 wave functions for the 1st excited state? AH! right!! I'm just over-complicating things.. thank you!

Comment: @Reety, no worries, we've all been there.